# Javascript hide/show layers

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show, layer

I am working with hiding and showing divs in javascript, basically I want to show one div, then when a button is clicked hide that div and show another. I can't quite figure the javascript out here's what I have at the moment but the second layer isnt showing when I click hide.

```
  <script language=javascript type='text/javascript'> 
    function hidediv() { 
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
    document.getElementById('layer').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    document.getElementById('topbar').style.visibility = 'visisble';
    } 
    else { 
    if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
    document.layer.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    document.topbar.visibility = 'visible'; 

    } 
    else { // IE 4 
    document.all.layer.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    document.all.topbar.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    } 
    } 
    }

    function showdiv() { 
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
    document.getElementById('layer').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
 document.getElementById('topbar').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } 
    else { 
    if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
    document.layer.visibility = 'visible'; 
document.topbar.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    } 
    else { // IE 4 
    document.all.layer.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
document.all.topbar.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } 
    } 
    } 
    </script>
```

and css:

```
 #topbar {
    background-image: url(images/back.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
height: 30px;
margin-top: 20px;
visibility: hidden;
}

#show {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#hide {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

#layer {
background-image: url(images/back.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

using standard html links like:

```
<a href="javascript:hidediv()">Hide</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

EDIT

okay switched to something completely new but it seems to not show after hiding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(function(){
  $('#showhide').click(function(){
     $('#layer').toggle();
     $('#topbar').toggle(); 
  });
});

and

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showhide">Show/Hide</a>
```

and

```
<div id="layer"></div>
```

Comment: I would strongly advise you to use jQuery to avoid the necessity to check for browser etc. It will certainly shorten your code, making it clearer and easier for you to debug.

Comment: Sadly, jquery isnt compatible with IE4 either. And i would suggest not supporting such old browsers.

Comment: I can't help you with your question, but the [BBC's Glow library](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/) *seems* to be compatible with the older generations of browsers.

Comment: @Amy IE4? The one released in 1997 with Win 98? I'm pretty sure that no-one uses that version anymore.

Comment: yes iv changed the code now to above but having small problem making it show

Comment: jQuery may "shorten" the code, but it will dramatically add to the page load when he won't be using 99.9% of its functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably help you: http://api.jquery.com/hide/ or the http://api.jquery.com/toggle/.

EDIT:

I am hoping that following example will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function(){

         $("#a").toggle();
         $("#b").toggle();

     });

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a">
    I am a.
  </div>

  <div id="b" style="display: none">
  I am b.
  </div>

  <div id="button">
    <button>Show/Hide</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks have tried some new stuff with jquery but now having problem with it hiding then quickly showing again, edited above.

Comment: Please take a look into the example I have added to my answer. I hope this will help you get going.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need jQuery for this.

Your functions could look like this:

```
function hideElement(elementId)
{
 document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = 'none';
}
function showElement(elementId)
{
 document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Then on page load, or in the css you can hide the first div. When the click happens you can then use `showElement` to show it.

Comment: Okay so this seems a better way to go but I can't get it to work, probably doing something stupid, check code above.